# Парсинг XML в T-SQL запросе

Tags: sql-server, xml

Объясните пожалуйста как распарсить XML в T-SQL

```
DECLARE
      @XML XML,
      @XmlDocument NVARCHAR (1000),
      @DocHandle INT,
      @nodeName VARCHAR (20);
SELECT
      @XML
      = 

'<CIR Name="SEP" Description="des_sep">
  <confi CreatedBy="domen\e123" DateCreated="2010-10-14T07:21:38">
    <xml>
      <DesiredConfigurationDigest xmlns="http://schemas.com">
        <!--Version: 5-->
           <Annotation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com">
            <DisplayName Text="Antivirus" ResourceId="ID-0a" />
            <Description Text="Test Antivirus" />
           </Annotation>
          <Settings>
            <RootComplexSetting>
                <Annotation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com">
                  <DisplayName Text="Is Symantec" ResourceId="ID-4a" />
                  <Description Text="" />
                </Annotation>
                <ScriptDiscoverySource Is64Bit="true">
                  <DiscoveryScriptBody ScriptType="VBScript">Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
If Not oShell.IsServiceRunning("Symantec") Then
  wscript.echo 1
End If</DiscoveryScriptBody>
                </ScriptDiscoverySource>
            </RootComplexSetting>
          </Settings>
      </DesiredConfigurationDigest>
    </xml>
  </confi>
</CIR>
<CIR Name="avg" Description="des_avg">
  <confi CreatedBy="domen\e124" DateCreated="2010-10-14T07:21:38">
    <xml>
      <DesiredConfigurationDigest xmlns="http://schemas.com">
        <!--Version: 5-->
           <Annotation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com">
            <DisplayName Text="Antivirus" ResourceId="ID-0b" />
            <Description Text="Test Antivirus avg" />
           </Annotation>
          <Settings>
            <RootComplexSetting>
                <Annotation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com">
                  <DisplayName Text="Is avg" ResourceId="ID-4b" />
                  <Description Text="" />
                </Annotation>
                <ScriptDiscoverySource Is32Bit="true">
                  <DiscoveryScriptBody ScriptType="VBScript">Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
If Not oShell.IsServiceRunning("avg") Then
  wscript.echo 2
End If</DiscoveryScriptBody>
                </ScriptDiscoverySource>
            </RootComplexSetting>
          </Settings>
      </DesiredConfigurationDigest>
    </xml>
  </confi>
</CIR>';
SET @nodeName = 'DisplayName';
SELECT
      *
FROM  ( SELECT
              x.y.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS a,
              x.y.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS b
        --FROM @xml.nodes('/CIR') AS x(y)
        FROM  @XML.nodes('//*[not(*)]') AS x(y) ) t1;
```

в результате хотелось бы  получить

```
 Name  | Description|CreatedBy    | DateCreated   |DisplayName |    Description      |  DisplayName |   ResourceId |    DiscoveryScriptBody
SEP   |des_sep       |domen\e123 |  2010-00-14T07:21:38|         Antivirus| Test Antivirus  |   Is Symantec   | ID-4a           |   Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") If Not oShell.IsServiceRunning("Symantec") Then   wscript.echo 1 End If
avg    |des_avg        |domen\e124| 2010-00-14T07:21:38|         Antivirus| Test Antivirus avg| Is avg         |    ID-4b           |   Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") If Not oShell.IsServiceRunning("avg") Then   wscript.echo 2 End If
```

или

```
   Name     | SEP
Description | des_sep
CreatedBy   | domen\e123
DateCreated | 2010-00-14T07:21:38
DisplayName | Antivirus
Description | Test Antivirus
DisplayName | Is Symantec
ResourceId  | ID-4a
DiscoveryScriptBody | VBScript">Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
```

при работе скрипта я получаю только

```
    DisplayName |
Description     |
DisplayName     |
Description     |
DiscoveryScriptBody |   Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") If Not oShell.IsServiceRunning("Symantec") Then   wscript.echo 1 End If
```

как вытащить остальные значения ?
я так понимаю, что проблема  в `//*[not(*)]` ?

Comment: x.y.value('@Text', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as b

Comment: при таком решении теряется значение DiscoveryScriptBody, и не выдает вторые значения к примеру x.y.value('@Name', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as b     Name="SEP" Description="des_sep" вытащит только SEP

Comment: Парсер xml на sql... Теперь я видел всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```sql
DECLARE @xml xml;
SET @xml = ...;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
    'http://schemas.com' AS ns,
    'http://schemas.microsoft.com' AS ms
    )
SELECT
    cir.x.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Name,
    cir.x.value('@Description', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Description,
    confi.x.value('@CreatedBy', 'nvarchar(100)') AS CreatedBy,
    confi.x.value('@DateCreated', 'datetime2(0)') AS DateCreated,
    digest.x.value('(ms:Annotation/ms:DisplayName/@Text)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS DisplayName,
    digest.x.value('(ms:Annotation/ms:Description/@Text)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Description,
    rcs.x.value('(ms:Annotation/ms:DisplayName/@Text)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS DisplayName,
    rcs.x.value('(ms:Annotation/ms:DisplayName/@ResourceId)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS ResourceId,
    src.x.value('(ns:DiscoveryScriptBody/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') AS DiscoveryScriptBody
FROM
    @xml.nodes('CIR') cir(x)
    OUTER APPLY cir.x.nodes('confi[1]') confi(x)
    OUTER APPLY confi.x.nodes('(xml/ns:DesiredConfigurationDigest)[1]') digest(x)
    OUTER APPLY digest.x.nodes('(ns:Settings/ns:RootComplexSetting)[1]') rcs(x)
    OUTER APPLY rcs.x.nodes('(ns:ScriptDiscoverySource)[1]') src(x);
```

Или даже так:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
    'http://schemas.com' AS ns,
    'http://schemas.microsoft.com' AS ms
    )
SELECT
    cir.x.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Name,
    cir.x.value('@Description', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Description,
    cir.x.value('(confi/@CreatedBy)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS CreatedBy,
    cir.x.value('(confi/@DateCreated)[1]', 'datetime2(0)') AS DateCreated,
    da.x.value('(ms:DisplayName/@Text)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS DisplayName,
    da.x.value('(ms:Description/@Text)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Description,
    rcsa.x.value('(ms:DisplayName/@Text)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS DisplayName,
    rcsa.x.value('(ms:DisplayName/@ResourceId)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS ResourceId,
    cir.x.value('(.//ns:DiscoveryScriptBody/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') AS DiscoveryScriptBody
FROM
    @xml.nodes('CIR') cir(x)
    OUTER APPLY cir.x.nodes('(.//ns:DesiredConfigurationDigest/ms:Annotation)[1]') da(x)
    OUTER APPLY cir.x.nodes('(.//ns:RootComplexSetting/ms:Annotation)[1]') rcsa(x);
```

Если эффективность критична, то лучше сравнить оба вариант на конкретных данных.